# How to create a horizontal scrollview with images of different sizes and orientations?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, interface-builder

I've been asked to implement something like this:

where it's a horizontal scrollview that could contain several images with different aspect ratios.

So I'd probably want to add an imageview to the scrollview for each image, but I'm not sure how I should fit the images to the imageviews.

Should I set the imageview's width to the width of the image and then set the mode to scale to fill?

I don't want to just aspect fill because I don't want to cut parts of the images off, and I don't want to aspect fit because I don't want blank space.

Does anyone know how to approach this? I know it's going to be a headache trying to get every image size to work, so if anyone has experience with this, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UICollectionView`, and calculate the right image width for all cells in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

you could make all the `UIImageView`s to have equal heights (the height of your `UIScrollView`) and set the `UIImageView`s' aspect ratios to the aspect ratios of the `UIImage`s they contain. then you can set the `UIImageView`s' `contentMode` property to `scaleToFill` without a problem...